# Cognito Userpool Facebook OAuth with Spring Security, there are any cache?

Tags: java, spring, facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm using Spring Security 5 with Cognito Userpool.

I implemented Facebook login via userpool using userpool OAuth2 APIs. I succeeded to login using my facebook account, but once I deleted a user from userpool (via deleteUser API), I fail to register again and encount `invalid_grant` error.

```
...
[nio-8090-exec-6] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider
[nio-8090-exec-6] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.authentication.OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider
[nio-8090-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP POST https://mydomain.auth.myregion.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token
[nio-8090-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
[nio-8090-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Writing [{grant_type=[authorization_code], code=[xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx], redirect_uri=[http://localhost:8090/login/oauth2/code/facebook]}] as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
[nio-8090-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 400 BAD_REQUEST
[nio-8090-exec-6] .s.a.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher : No event was found for the exception org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException
[nio-8090-exec-6] .s.o.c.w.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [invalid_grant] 

org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [invalid_grant] 
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.authentication.OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java:143) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:175) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java:186) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:160) [spring-security-oauth2-client-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ...
```

I tried to clear browser cache, but nothing happen.
However, I succeeded to login again *after about 30 minutes*, using same source code.

There are some caches on Cognito Userpool or Facebook authorization?

application.yml

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          facebook:
            clientId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            clientSecret: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            clientAuthenticationMethod: basic
            redirectUriTemplate: '{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}'
            authorizationGrantType: authorization_code
            scope:
              - openid
              - email
              - profile
              - aws.cognito.signin.user.admin
            clientName: Facebook
        provider:
          facebook:
            authorizationUri: https://mydomain.auth.myregion.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?identity_provider=Facebook
            tokenUri: https://mydomain.auth.myregion.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token
            jwkSetUri: https://cognito-idp.myregion.amazonaws.com/my_userpool_id/.well-known/jwks.json
            userInfoUri: https://mydomain.auth.myregion.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/userInfo
            userNameAttribute: sub
```

Comment: Could you resolve this issue?

Comment: No, I put off this problem...